# How can I create fullscreen crossfading slideshow on background without white flicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a crossfade fullscreen slideshow on my webpage with HTML and CSS, however it's not working well.
I could create crossfading on background images, but there is a problem.
In first loading, there are white flickers between each images.
I don't want to avoid white flickers.
How can I fix them?

I've wrote with HTML and CSS to create a crossfade slideshow.

```html
<body>
  <div class="slideshow">
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideshow {
  height: 100vh;
  weight: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  animation: slide 24s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  25% {
    background-image: url('../images/2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }

  50% {
    background-image: url('../images/3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }

  75% {
    background-image: url('../images/4.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

I don't need white flickers and apply a beautiful crossfade slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Flickers happen because the browser paints a new image, probably.

Try creating individual <div>s for each slide, position them absolute, and simply fade each of them away.

```
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slide slide-1"></div>
        <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
        <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
        <div class="slide slide-4"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; /* makes it full size */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.slide.active { 
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

With CSS only:

```
@keyframes slide-1 {
    0% , 40% , 100% { opacity: 0; }
    20%             { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes slide-2 {
    0% , 20% , 60% , 100% { opacity: 0; }
    40%                   { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes slide-3 {
    0% , 40% , 80% , 100% { opacity: 0; }
    60%                   { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes slide-4 {
    0% , 60% , 100%  { opacity: 0; }
    80%              { opacity: 1; }
}

.slide-1 { animation: slide-1 24s infinite; background-image: url('../images/1.jpg'); }
.slide-2 { animation: slide-2 24s infinite; background-image: url('../images/2.jpg'); }
.slide-3 { animation: slide-3 24s infinite; background-image: url('../images/3.jpg'); }
.slide-4 { animation: slide-4 24s infinite; background-image: url('../images/4.jpg'); }
```

---

Or with JS:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    var current = document.querySelector('.slide.active');

    if (current.nextElementSibling) {
        current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        current.parentElement.firstElementChild.classList.add('active');
    };

    current.classList.remove('active');
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply!!
Where should I put background images like 'background-image' property?

Comment: Glad it helped! If this is adequate, please mark it as the accepted answer, for future readers. Best of luck!

Comment: But there is no description about background-image, please help me!!
Now I'm doing with the js code that you gave...

Comment: You put the image insed the div :)

Comment: I'm doing the only css version now, but it seems all images are overlapping...
How can I fix that?

Comment: overlaping - what do you mean? The images are placed on top of one another, and they fade in/out in the same place. Do you mean for the animation to first finish fading-out (leave a blank screen) before running the fading-in on the next image?

Comment: Yes! exactly you said. Before the first image fade out, the next image and after images fade in...